# How can I get the runtime of a movie in .m4v format?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, m4v

How can I get the runtime of a movie (in my case .m4v) using C# .NET?

I am unsure what API to use for this.

Answer (score 4):

The way i have done in a few of my project is using the MediaInfo library : [Link Here](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
namespace MediaInfoLib
{
    public enum StreamKind
    {
        General,
        Video,
        Audio,
        Text,
        Chapters,
        Image
    }

    public enum InfoKind
    {
        Name,
        Text,
        Measure,
        Options,
        NameText,
        MeasureText,
        Info,
        HowTo
    }

    public enum InfoOptions
    {
        ShowInInform,
        Support,
        ShowInSupported,
        TypeOfValue
    }

    public enum InfoFileOptions
    {
        FileOption_Nothing      = 0x00,
        FileOption_NoRecursive  = 0x01,
        FileOption_CloseAll     = 0x02,
        FileOption_Max          = 0x04
    };


    public class MediaInfo
    {
        //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)  
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_New();
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void   MediaInfo_Delete(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, byte[] Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64  MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64  MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void   MediaInfo_Close(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Option(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Option, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Option(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Option,  IntPtr Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_State_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Count_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber);

        //MediaInfo class
        public MediaInfo()
        {
            Handle = MediaInfo_New();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().IndexOf("Windows")==-1)
                MustUseAnsi=true;
            else
                MustUseAnsi=false;
        }
        ~MediaInfo() { MediaInfo_Delete(Handle); }
        public int Open(String FileName)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr FileName_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(FileName);
                int ToReturn = (int)MediaInfoA_Open(Handle, FileName_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(FileName_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return (int)MediaInfo_Open(Handle, FileName);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Init(Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset)
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(Handle, File_Size, File_Offset);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size)
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(Handle, Buffer, Buffer_Size);
        }
        public Int64 Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get()
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(Handle);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Finalize()
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(Handle);
        }
        public void Close() { MediaInfo_Close(Handle); }
        public String Inform()
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Parameter_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Parameter);
                String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter_Ptr, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Parameter_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
        }
        public String Option(String Option, String Value)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Option_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Option);
                IntPtr Value_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Value);
                String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Option(Handle, Option_Ptr, Value_Ptr));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Option_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Value_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Option(Handle, Option, Value));
        }
        public int State_Get() { return (int)MediaInfo_State_Get(Handle); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { return (int)MediaInfo_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
        private IntPtr Handle;
        private bool MustUseAnsi;

        //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
        public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(StreamKind, -1); }
    }

} //NameSpace
```

Usage :

```
using System;
using MediaInfoLib;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MediaInfo info = new MediaInfo();
            info.Open(@"E:\Songs Collection\Video's\Hindi Song's\Ajab.Si.By.HFZ.avi");
            var movie_lenstr = info.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "Duration");
            Int32 movie_len;
            if (Int32.TryParse(movie_lenstr, out movie_len))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length of movie in milli-second : {0}", movie_len);
            }
            info.Close();

        }

    }

}
```

There are many parameters available, so go through the documentation once

- for x86 OS : [Here](http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.61/MediaInfo_DLL_0.7.61_Windows_i386_WithoutInstaller.7z)
- for x64 OS : [Here](http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.61/MediaInfo_DLL_0.7.61_Windows_x64_WithoutInstaller.7z)

**Note** :

1. Place the `mediainfo.dll` in the application dir / system dir
2. Make sure you use the proper build format of dll for x64/x86 OS, else it may lead to

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Comment: I think there is something incorrect here.... when I run this, it says my second for my movie (which is 1:21:05) is saying that it's 4865616 seconds. Am I missing something here? Why is it getting the incorrect duration?

Comment: "Duration"  Play time of the stream in millisecond